# Pan-sharpening of NIR band

Tags: pansharpening

I want to create pansharpened image from landsat 8 composite image (R,G,B and NIR bands) in ArcGIS using Esri method in "Create Pan-sharpened Raster Dataset" tool. 
For weighting I used recommended value from ESRI resource website:

```
Band 1 weight: 0.166
Band 2 weight: 0.160
Band 3 weight: 0.166
Band 4 weight: 0.3
```

I have got the result where red, green and blue bands are sharpened but NOT NIR one.

Any suggestion what I might doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arc is not the greatest for this, I'd need to know what the gsd of your hri is. Landsat isn't natively producing composites. Depends on what you're trying to do/classify. If you're attempting vegetation (CIR/NDVI), you'll probably be swapping your true red for NIR. Pan sharpening in it's simplest terms is stretching your low res (MSI) pixel values over a high res image using tie points. Your band combination will depend on the phenomenology you want displayed, landsat 8 has more than 4 bands (which is why my assumption from your post is you're looking at vegetation). Caveat, I've never attempted to pan sharpen landsat, at 30m resolution you're classifying in a small scale, so it wouldn't make a difference at that extent regardless.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Swoping red for NIR worked. Also when using Gram-Schmidt method, Landsat 8 sensor type can be specified. Then it worked for me even without swoping. Yeah, I need it for getting water index (NDWI) to extract shoreline.